# IIS custom site HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

Tags: iis

I've created a new site within IIS and pointed to my local Documents directory

```
C:\Users\name\Documents
```

via

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

The error I'm getting is

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

I've checked the properties of the Documents folder under Security. for IIS_IUSRS, Read & Execute, List folder contents and Read are checked.

Others like SYSTEM, myUsername, Administrators have more rights to this folder.

Not sure what I'm missing here, please advise.

Comment: Try NETWORK_SVC.  Your IIS Application Pool is probably running under that account.

Comment: nops.... didn't work

Comment: do I've to apply security at my username directory or users directory or Documents itself which I've been doing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS - 401.3 - Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162553/iis-401-3-unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

Download Procmon from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and start tracing. Reproduce the issue and stop procmon.

Filter procmon trace for "access denied". It'll tell you what permissions are needed and for which folder.

Share a screenshot of procmon trace if you find it difficult to analyze and I will try and guide you.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Users\name\Documents" would typically be a terrible place to put a web site.  It is essentially the same as "My Documents" which is a special Windows folder.  And it would have a number of non-web site folders.  Try using C:\Web (or something like that) and add IIS_IUSRS to that folder.

BUT, if you really want to use your My Documents as the root of a web site, you can create a web.config file in C:\Users\name\Documents with the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```