# Link IIS to Image Hosting Server Folder. (Link to network share for only hosting images)

Tags: iis-10, network-share

All.
The network share is not running IIS, it is not running anything but is simply used as a share where all images and media files are uploaded too.

In IIS, I created a Virtual Directory UNDER the domain and pointed it to my image server \\ImageServer\Files
In IIS for this folder, it displays all the sub-folders. (As seen in the image below)
However, when I try to bring the image up to view, it gives a 404 error and points to the directory of the Domain for the file not being there.
It thinks the files are stored on the local server, and not from a share.
All permissions are set, everything is running correctly so far on the server(s)
Except this.

What am I missing here? 
Do I need to create another

[image: IIS Shared Server Folder]

```
==GENERAL_REQUEST_START== 
SiteId 15 
AppPoolId Radio 
ConnId 1610626168 
RawConnId 0 
RequestURL http://example.com:80/host/files/Covers/Big/1_02282020070502823.jpg
RequestVerb GET
```

.

```
==MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS==   
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER   
HttpStatus 404  
HttpReason Not Found  
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified.  (0x80070002)
```

.

```
==FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_START== 

FileName G:\Inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\host\files\Covers\Big\1_02282020070502823.jpg 
UserName IUSR 
DomainName NT AUTHORITY
```

Comment: If you don't use a domain service account as application pool identity, which can access that file share, you'd better configure "Physical Path Credentials".

Comment: I do have a domain service account on it.

Comment: Then what does FRT say about those 404? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Updated information with the trace route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue and thought I would share it. 
I would like to start off with this.
For whatever reason, the webpage gave me a 401 error, for authentication.
That is when I looked it up for IIS Authentication and found the second part below. And it worked!

(This first section was already in place) 
**Part I**
Application Pool
Choose the custom Pool for your website.
Choose [**Advanced Settings**] from the right panel.
Under Identity
Click on the Elips
Choose [**Custom Account**]
Type in the username of the domain with administration and domain roles.
Type in the password and confirm it.
Click OK then OK again.

**Part II**
(This I found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23494758), and modified it to work with the Pool)
Click on the website name.
Under IIS
Choose [**Authentication**]
Choose [**Anonymous Authentication**]
Choose Edit from the Right panel
Select [**Application pool identity**]
Click OK.

I was so happy when I saw this actually working.