# .NetCore React JS: How To Prevent .gltf File From Being Routed?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, babylonjs

In `debug` mode my code is working fine.

```
window.BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(
        "",
        "/assets/logo/3D/",
        "logo.gltf",
        that.scene,
        function (meshes) { ..... });
```

My `.gltf` 3D asset is stored in `public/assets/logo/3D` with the name `logo.gltf`. I am using `.NetCore` as the web server.

Somehow whenever the loader requests `.gltf` file, it returns `html`. It suppose to return `json` (`gltf`). Image files like `.jpg`, '.png', etc... are fine.

I have specify the mime type for `.gltf` in my `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".gltf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="model/gltf+json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

It retrieves as `content-type: text/html`. It suppose to be `model/gltf+json`.

How can I load the file safely?

Comment: Could you please post your `Startup` code?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `ASP.NET Core` to return correct `Content-Type` by adding your MIME type to file provider. In `Startup` add `StaticFileOptions` argument with extended content type provider to your `app.UseStaticFiles()` call

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

If you want to serve such static files via IIS you need to add a static file processing module before `ASP.NET Core` pipeline

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <!-- added staticGltf handler to serve .gltf files -->
    <add name="staticGltf" path="*.gltf" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore you_config_here />

  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".gltf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="model/gltf+json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But in this case you might need to address possible issues with routes (such as `ASP.NET Core` is configured to search files in `wwwroot` folder but IIS will search in app root instead) and [insufficient file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162553/iis-401-3-unauthorized).

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander answer is the correct answer. Here is my `Startup` file if anyone wants to know.

Inside the `Configure` method:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json";

var staticFileOpt = new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOpt);
app.UseSpaStaticFiles(staticFileOpt);
```

There is `UseStaticFiles()` and `UseSpaStaticFiles()`. I am using `ReactJS` as the SPA framework, that is why I need `UseSpaStaticFiles()` too.